# web-stick disconnects randomly

Tags: networking, usb

Every now and then it happens that my **web-stick** disconnects all by itself.
About half a minute after that it connects again and I can establish a new connection to my umts-provider. But it gets annoying.

My modem is:

```
lsusb | grep -i huawei:

Bus 001 Device 024: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
```

On https://gist.github.com/Rosika2/030b75abbd24f98cba5c099c1435b7c3  I posted the output of my syslog-messages which might (?????) give a clue
as to what´s happening. But I really need help with that as I´m bit at a loss here.

P.S.:
my system: Lubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K.,
it seems like I´ve got too many usb-devices connected to my hub(s). I was able to discuss this matter on https://itsfoss.community/t/web-stic...ndomly/2771/13 .
The disconnection seems to be directly linked to the low power due to my hub-configuration.

I´m going to try to solve the problem by changing that.

Cheers